# Diagonal Difference in a Matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, matrix

I was trying to solve this [*problem on Hackerrank*](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen):

> Given a square matrix, calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.

*My code:*

```
 public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
    // Write your code here
    int d1=0;
    int d2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr.get(i).size();j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                d1=d1+arr.get(i).get(j);
            }
            if((i+j)==arr.size()-1);
            {
                d2=d2+arr.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }
    }
    int ans =d1-d2;
    return Math.abs(ans);
    }
}
```

The following input

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
9 8 9
```

Should produce the output of `2`, but my code gives `34`. Can anyone explain why does that happens?

Comment: According to that hackerrank page you linked, the answer you get back should be "2", not "15"

Comment: Have you tried to debug it to see where is the problem comming from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given a **square matrix**, calculate the absolute difference between the sums of its diagonals.

Since according to the description, we are given a *square matrix*, there's no need of creating a nested loop. And we can get rid of `if`-statements as well.

The code can be simplified to:

```
public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
    int d1 = 0;
    int d2 = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        d1 += arr.get(i).get(i);
        d2 += arr.get(arr.size() - 1 - i).get(i);
    }
    
    return Math.abs(d1 - d2);
}
```

*This solution passes all test cases*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is a stray semicolon:

```
        // right here----------v
        if((i+j)==arr.size()-1);
        {
            d2=d2+arr.get(i).get(j);
        }
```

Removing it should get you the correct answer of "2"